# Android browser only loads one Facebook comment

Tags: android, html, facebook, browser

I am having this weird issue where the Android stock browser only loads one comment for the Facebook social comment plugin on a page. This wouldn't be that big of a deal, but my app uses a webview to display comments. I have verified this on two of my devices so far. When I use Chrome this issue is none existent, but when I use the Android stock browser, it seems to cut off data.

My html code is very simple

```
   <html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
    <head><title>Facebooktest</title>

    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>(function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    
        <fb:comments href="http://example.com" width="470" num_posts="10" mobile="true"></fb:comments>
    
    </body>
   </html>
```

This is the screenshot of what shows up in my app

[image]

And this is the view from my tablet loading the webpage in the Android browser

[image]

---

## Solved

It took about two weeks, but the comments started showing up again. I am assuming it was an issue with Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has started again, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/240570862734465  There is a ticket submitted to FB about this.  Comments were working properly for a short time, then started cutting off again.